# Porque essa comparação entre arrays não funciona no Python?

Tags: python, array, numpy, ciência-de-dados

Considere os 3 arrays abaixo
Retorne o valor do array `xarr` se o valor for `True` no array `cond`. Caso contrário, retorne o valor do array `yarr`.

```
import numpy as np

xarr = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5])
yarr = np.array([2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5])
cond = np.array([True, False, True, True, False])

#Minha resposta ao problema

result1 = np.arange(cond.size)
a=0
for i in cond:
    if i == True:
        #print(xarr[a])
        result1[a] = xarr[a]
        a=a+1
    else:
        #print(yarr[a])
        result1[a] = yarr[a]
        a=a+1
print(result1)
```

Como resposta eu obtenho isso:

```
[1 2 1 1 2]
```

Mas gostaria de obter isso:

```
[1.1 2.2 1.3 1.4 2.5]
```

Fiquei confuso porque quando uso os "prints" que estão dentro dos "if/else", eles retornam o valor que eu desejo, mas quando atribuo eles ao novo "array" eles não vão como imagino.

Qual a lógica que estou errado ou deixando passar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pela forma como `result1` foi criada, o numpy assumiu como `int64` e e' por isso que o resultado que esta a dar sao números inteiros. Para se ver isto, basta fazer: `print(result1.dtype)`. Para mais informação sobre isto, ver: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Os `print()` dentro dos if else dao o valor que se pretende porque sao os dados originais, que sao do tipo `float64` (por exemplo: `print(yarr.dtype)`).

Quanto a utilização da variável `a`, nao ha nada de "errado", no entanto, a utilização e' estranha e a lógica de incremento ora no if ora no else nao me parece uma boa pratica. Para o tipo de situação em que se pretende ter acesso ao objecto e ao seu índice, o Python fornece a `enumerate()`. Por exemplo:

```
for indice, obj in enumerate(lista):
    <resto do codigo>
```

No entanto, a grande questão aqui e' sobre a estratégia geral do código. Fazer um `for` com numpy como se estivéssemos a usar listas nao e' a forma mais adequada. Ha muitos conteúdos sobre isto na Internet. Procurar por exemplo "vetorização numpy", no motor de busca preferido.

Com numpy, o ideal e' usarmos as ferramentas que a biblioteca fornece. Ha uma que me parece util para este caso:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Assim:

```
import numpy as np

xarr = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5])
yarr = np.array([2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5])
cond = np.array([True, False, True, True, False])

print(np.where(cond,xarr,yarr))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas, vou ler mais a documentação do NumPy pra conhecer as possibilidades, acho que ainda estou pensando como se estivesse com listas, como você falou! Resolveu o problema, e vou tentar melhores práticas;